# How to migrate a web server and app server to azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

If I have a 3-tier application on-premises and the three tiers are as follows: Web Server, App server, and DB server. Can I migrate the web and app server to Azure app services? or will I've to deploy the app server on another Azure service?

Answer (score 2):

For an easy migration you could use an [Azure Web App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/web/) to host the sites you currently run with your on-premise Web Server.

Assuming your App Server should expose an API and is written in either .NET, PHP, Node.js, Java, or Python - you can deploy it using an [Azure API App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/api/).

If you talking about SQL Server, use Azure SQL Database (Read [SQL Server database migration to Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-cloud-migrate) for potential limitations.

---

You can also consider to *containerize* your application and deploy it to [Azure Kubernetes Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/kubernetes-service/) (AKS)

Comment: In Azure, you pay for an App Service Plan which can host multiple App Services (e. g. your API App and Web App). So the App Service Plan is a container for your Apps

Comment: Which app service I should add a CDN endpoint for (Web App or App service)?

Comment: It should be noted that App Service also supports docker containers. It even supports deployments through a docker-compose file or a kubernetes yaml definition.